# Window.open Invalid Argument in Javascript

Tags: javascript, popup, window.open

I've been trying to get this window to show up as a pop up. When I click on the hyperlink, it gives me "Invalid argument" at character 4.

```
window.open("notifMsg.htm","My Notification","status=no,height=545,width=433,resizable=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no");
```

`window.open("notifMsg.htm")` works, but once I add more parameters it keeps giving invalid argument. I've looked at w3 schools and this looks to be the format.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: w3schools is not known for having the most correct information. I would refer instead to the MDN. In fact if you look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open) you will see that they use the syntax that @pointy has pointed out. Using an underscore instead of a space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Internet Explorer insists that window names be valid identifiers. Your name has a space in it. Try "My_Notification" instead.